# 404 Error while URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using url routing for a webform in my project. Its working fine but I've a problem. My project structure is just like as shown below.

[image]

I've a login page its inside the Index.aspx page. Once I enter the user name and password, the it will redirect to the Home.aspx. This is my routing class

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute(
                "User",
                "Users/{id}",
                "~/Modules/UserMgmt/Users.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute(
                "Leave",
                "LeaveApply/{id}",
                "~/Modules/LeaveMgmt/LeaveApply.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Index","Index","~/Index.aspx");
        }
```

My anchor tag is just like as below

```
<a href="../../Users/18">Users</a>
```

When I login the first time it will entered into the Home.aspx correctly as shown below.

[image]

If I redirect the page again using this anchor tag it will show the 404 Error and it can't get the parent rout and the page is as shown below

[image]

If I rewrite the anchor tag like as below

```
 <a href="../Users/18">Users</a>
```

It will work but will work at first time. How I solve this problem. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag can use a path relative to the root of your site:

```
<a href="/URLRouting/Users/18">Users</a>
```

This will point to `http://localhost/URLRouting/Users/18` regardless of what path the current page is in.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. Actually the Name URLRouting is the Project name that is automatically comes to the url when I configured my project with the Local IIS Web Server. So I can't mention that name with the url Directly.